# style first character of a paragraph using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i'm looking for a way to style the first character in a paragraph. I've used this function to return the first character

```
var x= $(".about p:eq(0)").text();
alert(x.charAt(0));
```

but don't know how to style it

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

Comment: Wrap a span around it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use CSS3 to style your first character.

```
p::first-letter { 
  font-size: 200%;
  color: #8A2BE2;
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/vhyqowde/

More Info:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp

---

Javascript approach:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var elem = $("p").contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType == 3 }).first(),
        text = elem.text().trim(),
        first = text.slice(0, 1);

    if (!elem.length)
        return;

    elem[0].nodeValue = text.slice(first.length);
    elem.before('<span>' + first + '</span>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kynt4pot/

Comment: Note: as you can see in the JSFiddle, the space before the `<b>` element is gone after the Javascript is run.

Answer (score 6):

Use CSS `first-letter` selector

```
p::first-letter {
    color: #FF69B4;
}
```

This will select and style the first letter of every `<p>` element.  **[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g0fwuy2m/2/)**

Comment: OP asked for a jQuery solution originally.. isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

With Jquery : http://jsfiddle.net/2wkjyz4g/2/

```
var x= $(".about p:eq(0)").text();
var text='<span class="fChar">'+x.charAt(0)+'</span>';
$(".about p:eq(0)").html(text + x.slice(1,x.length));
```

With css : http://jsfiddle.net/pe5Loaqn/

```
.about p:first-child:first-letter {
    color:red;
}
```

because you asked for jquery solution and you selected 1st(`:eq(0)`) `<p>` tag.

**update after @Garconis' comment**

```js
var parent = "p"

function styleFirst(elem){
 var content = $(elem).contents()[0];
  if(content.nodeType == 1){
    styleFirst(content);
  }else if(content.nodeType == 3){
     $(elem).html(style(String(content.nodeValue)));
  }
}

function style(txt){
    var newTxt = '<span class="fChar">' + txt.charAt(0) + '</span>';
  return newTxt + txt.slice(1, txt.length);
}
styleFirst(parent);
```

```css
.fChar {
    color:red;
}

span{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span><span>Win</span>ter</span> is <span>here</span> !!!!!!!!!!!</p>
```

**Update in code:**

Can retain the nodes in the para tag also can style 1st text character even if it is nested in any other element.

The code can be updated to check if 1st char is space/tab etc in `style()` method and subsequent styling can be applied.

Comment: Issue with your jQuery version is that it also strips out any HTML within that paragraph element.

Comment: Updated to add your suggestion. @Garconis. Also it made me think what if, 1st char of para does not belong to a textNode? So I added that part as well.

Comment: Here is my solution. I'm sure it could use improvement. But I only wanted it to affect pure text... http://jsfiddle.net/Garconis/g72a4h03/

Answer (score 1):

After having the same initial question, I decided to take bits and pieces of other's code, and create my own solution/answer. Here is my method.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Garconis/g72a4h03/**

Reference notes in the jQuery to understand some of the reasoning.

```js
(function($) {

  // find each instance of your target
  $('p').each(function() {

    // now check if the first character is "<" character
    // if is NOT a "<" character, then continue
    if ($(this).html()[0] != "<") {
      // good, now search the contents of the first TEXT_NODE within the selector
      var node = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
          return this.nodeType == 3
        }).first(),
        // check the start of the string (which is what the ^ is for)
        // find any white space (via the "\s")
        // and chunks of contiguous whitespace, which is what the + is for on "\s+"
        // and keep finding all instances at the start, which is what the global "/g" is for
        // and convert them into nothing
        text = node.text().replace(/^\s+/g, ''),
        // now start at the beginning (0 position) and grab the first character
        first = text.slice(0, 1);

      // if the first node isn't a TEXT_NODE, then stop here
      if (!node.length)
        return;

      // remove the text character that we grabbed
      node[0].nodeValue = text.slice(first.length);
      // now add it back, before the node we checked, with a wrapper
      node.before('<span class="fs-dropcap">' + first + '</span>');

    };

  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
span.fs-dropcap {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<p>&nbsp;"[yo]"This is a test <b>&nbsp; Other HTML <a href="#0;">tester</a> should not be affected by manipulations</b></p>
<hr>
<p>    This is a test <b>&nbsp; Other HTML <a href="#0;">tester</a> should not be affected by manipulations</b></p>
<hr>
<p><span>span tag here</span> This is a test <b>&nbsp; Other HTML <a href="#0;">tester</a> should not be affected by manipulations</b></p>
<hr>
<p><a href="#0">test</a> This is a test <b>Other HTML should not be affected by manipulations</b>
</p>
<hr>
<p>This is a test <b>Other HTML should not be affected by manipulations</b></p>
<hr>
<p>&nbsp; This is a test "Other HTML should not be affected by manipulations"
</p>
<hr>
<p><u>&nbsp;&nbsp;tester&nbsp;&nbsp;</u> This is a test "Other HTML should not be affected by manipulations"
</p>
```