# How can I style the first character of a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have no control over the HTML in this project, so everything has to be done with JavaScript/Jquery.

I have multiple pages coming from a server. Some of these tables have footers with footnotes. The first character of these footnotes is either a * or a †

Sometimes the page will have multiple tables.

I can't use ::first-letter, because it selects the symbol  AND the first letter. I need the padding to be only to the right of the symbol

I need to add padding to the right of these characters to separate them from the text.

I've successfully been able to get the symbols. As you can see in my code, I select the class, find the spans in the class, get the text, and convert them to sub-strings.
I then get the first character of each one, and when I console.log my results, I see the symbols.
I'm now trying to wrap them in a span with some inline styling, but I'm getting a "jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed." error.

The HTML code is generated in xsl documents, but here's the table footer taken from the inspector:

```
<div class="article-table-descriptions" style="width: 100%;">
    <span id="tblfn4">*footer text.</span>
    <span id="tblfn5">†footer text.</span>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {

let chars;
let tableFooterSpans = $('.article-table-descriptions').find('span').text().split('.');

$(tableFooterSpans).each(function(i, str){
    chars = str.charAt(0);
    $(chars).wrap("<span style='color: lime;'></span>");
   })
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [style first character of a paragraph using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872101/style-first-character-of-a-paragraph-using-jquery)

Comment: Tried that already. I updated the question.

Comment: add some html to your question

Comment: There are no HTML pages in this project. It's all generated in xsl files. That being said, I'll pull some of the generated code from the inspector

Comment: Use regex to check if the character is a letter and do what you need based on the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var span = $('.article-table-descriptions > span');

    span.each(function(index, el){
    
       var span_html =  $(el).html();

       $(el).html("<span style='color: lime;'>"+ span_html.charAt(0)  +"</span>" + span_html.substring(1,span_html.length));

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article-table-descriptions" style="width: 100%;">
    <span id="tblfn4">*footer text.</span>
    <span id="tblfn5">†footer text.</span>
</div>
<div class="article-table-descriptions" style="width: 100%;">
    <span id="tblfn6">*footer text.</span>
    <span id="tblfn7">†footer text.</span>
</div>

<div class="article-table-descriptions" style="width: 100%;">
    <span id="tblfn8">*footer text.</span>
    <span id="tblfn9">†footer text.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, that makes my footer text completely vanish, but I like your approach. I'm going to see if I can tweak it to make it work.

Comment: @mediabloke check your CSS and DOM tags, probably you have some another markup and you need to mobify something

Comment: Edited the question to include: Sometimes the page will have multiple tables.

Comment: that works! Although for some reason, it's pushing the text to the next line.

Comment: @mediabloke i updated code, please check, and please add screenshot, don't understand what do you mean by `pushing the text to the next line`

Comment: @mediabloke I don't see that happening on my browser. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. Like you said, there's probably some other styling that's messing with it. I'm digging.

Comment: @mediabloke chrome, also tested on safari, works fine, give me 2 minutes to check it

Comment: @mediabloke take a look at your `span` style, probably you have something like `display:block` if so, change `span` style to `display:inline-block`

Comment: Came here to say that. Changing it to inline-block did it. Thanks everyone, I only hope that the forehead shape in my laptop goes away soon.

Answer (score 0):

First get all the appropriate `span` elements before you try obtaining the first character. Then loop through spans, getting the first character and getting the string minus first character, wrap the first character, then update `span`.

```js
$( () => {

  const $spans = $( '.article-table-descriptions > span' );

  $spans.each( ( i, span ) => {
      
    const $span = $( span );
    const str   = $span.text();
    const char  = str.slice( 0, 1 );
    const _str  = str.slice( 1, str.length );

    $span.html( `<span class="highlight--char">${char}</span>${_str}` );
    
  } );
  
} );
```

```css
.highlight--char {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="article-table-descriptions" style="width: 100%;">
    <span id="tblfn4">*footer text 1a.</span>
    <span id="tblfn5">†footer text 1b.</span>
</div>

<div class="article-table-descriptions" style="width: 100%;">
    <span id="tblfn4">*footer text 2a.</span>
    <span id="tblfn5">†footer text 2b.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @mediabloke do you want all the `footer text` to be on one line even if there is more than one table description?

Comment: No. I want each footer line to be on it's own row

Comment: Well, that's what my answer and @20yco's answer is doing is doing. Must be some other styles from your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**without jQuery** you can do something like that

```js
let tableFooterSpans = document.querySelectorAll('.article-table-descriptions > span');

tableFooterSpans.forEach(e => e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(/(†|\*)?/g,"<span style='color: lime;margin-right:5px'>$1</span>"));
```

```html
<div class="article-table-descriptions">
  <span>†text1</span> <span>*text2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this instead of usig `wrap()`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

let chars;
let tableFooterSpans = $('.article-table-descriptions').find('span').text().split('.');

console.log("1",tableFooterSpans);

$(tableFooterSpans).each(function(i, str){
    chars = str.charAt(0);
    console.log("2", chars);
    $("#test").append("<span style='color : yellow'>"+chars+"</span>");
   })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article-table-descriptions" style="width: 100%;">
    <span id="tblfn4">*footer text.</span>
    <span id="tblfn5">†footer text.</span>
</div>

<div id="test">test</div>
```